# Symbol lookup error: _FileName_: undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove

Tags: c++, fortran, linker-errors

So I'm working on linking together a Fortran and a C++ code, and I'm getting the above error when I try and run the executable. I've done some searching for other solutions, and none of the things I've found so far have helped. I'll try and include everything, but I'm not that great with this kind of stuff so if there's anything else that is needed/useful to see let me know and I'll go grab it.

Makefile:

```
LDLIBS = -I/share/apps/intel/composer_xe_2011.sp1.10.319/mkl/include \
         -L/share/apps/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/mkl/lib/intel64 \
         -I/share/apps/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/mkl/interfaces/lapack95/source\
         -mkl -openmp -reentrancy threaded

INCLUDE = -I/path/mstl/include \
          -I/path/mstl/include/physics \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2 \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/algebra \
          -I/path/mstl/include/mat2/analysis \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/data \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/geometry \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/group \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/spline \
          -I/path/mstl/include/math2/probabilityandstatistics

LIBRARY = -L/path/mstl/lib

FC = ifort -c             #f compiler
CC = icc -c               #c compiler
LK = ifort -v -o ../abXX  #linker

CF = -mcmodel=large -i-dynamic -no-ipo -r8 -xW -traceback -fpe0 #f compile flags
OF = $(CF) -O2                                                  #f optimization flags
DF = $(CF) -g -debug -fpskchk -C -warn interfaces               #f debug flags

OPTIONS = -O -loops -lstdc++ -lmstl.icc          #c compile flags
LKOPS = -icc -lstdc++ -lmstl.icc -cxxlib -lintlc #linking options for C libs

COMP = $(FC) $(OF)                               #fortran compiler
CMP = $(CC) $(LIBRARY) $(INCLUDE) $(OPTIONS)     #C++ compiler
LINK = $(LK) $(OF)                               #program linker

MODULES = list of all fortran .o files here. 

COBJS = list of all c++ .o files here.

.cpp.o:
       $(CMP) $<

.f.o:
       $(COMP) $<

../abXX: $(MODULES) $(COBJS)
        $(LINK) $(MODULES) $(COBJS) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBRARY) $(INCLUDE) $(LKOPS)

clean:
      rm -v -f *.o *.mod ../abXX
```

.mybashrc:

```
echo "I exist in mybashrc"

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/INTEL/bin

source /opt/INTEL/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/composerxe/mkl/lib/intel64/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/:$LD_LIB_PATH

export INTEL_LICENSE_FILE = /opt/INTEL/licenses/client.lic

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
```

error message:

```
./../abXX: symbol lookup error: ./../abXX: undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove
```

I've also run the following little script looking for other undefined symbols:

```
nm --line-numbers --print-file-name --undefined-only --no-sort *.o > errorlist.txt
grep _intel_fast_ errorlist.txt > intelerrors.txt
```

When I do this I actually find that there are a large number of undefined references to _intel_fast_memcpy and _intel_fast_memset among the Fortran files. the _intel_fast_memmove only appears as missing in one of the cpp files.

I also found this weird because the Fortran code without the c runs just fine. I don't make any changes to the Fortran code. I just remove the definition of INCLUDE, LIBRARY, CC, OPTIONS, LKOPS, CMP, and COBJS from the specified make file and the recipe for ../abXX becomes

```
$(LINK) $(MODULES) $(LDLIBS)
```

I think I've included everything I've seen asked for on other threads I've looked at with similar errors, I can post anything else that might be useful as well.

EDIT: As requested:

results of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4:/opt/INTEL/debugger_2016/libipt/intel64/lib:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/../tbb/lib/intel64_lin/gcc4.4:/opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/../compiler/lib/intel64_lin::/opt/intel/composerxe/mkl/lib/intel64/:/opt/intel/composerxe/mkl/lib/intel64/:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64
```

results of `ldd ../abXX'

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb51b8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003171800000)
libintlc.so.5 => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5 (0x00007fc93b678000)
libmkl_intel_lp64.so => /opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so (0x00007fc93ab68000)
libmkl_intel_thread.so => /opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so (0x00007fc939238000)
libmkl_core.so => /opt/INTEL/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so (0x00007fc937820000)
libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00007fc937528000)
libifport.so.5 => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libifport.so.5 (0x00007fc9373f0000)
libifcoremt.so.5 => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libifcoremt.so.5 (0x00007fc937178000)
libimf.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00007fc936da8000)
libsvml.so => /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.10.319/compiler/lib/intel64/libsvml.so (0x00007fc936628000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000316b000000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003171400000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000316b400000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000316b800000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000316ac00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000316a800000)
```

Comment: You have typos in the CF and DF lines, besides using options which were already obsolete in that 6 year old compiler.

Comment: Don't put your name or Thanks under your posts. Your name is appended automatically and is displayed on the right from your icon.

Answer (score 0):

Intel compilers come with a setup shell file. For bash, those will be `ifortvars.sh` and `iccvars.sh`. Source those to have the environment (here, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) setup properly.

Check the file that you produce with ldd. If your environment is not properly setup it will tell you which `.so` files are not found.

Comment: I added both of those to the .mybashrc file, but it appears to have had no real change. I think the

`source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`

was already doing this. When I check the executable with ldd it looks like all of the printed libraries are pointing to defined paths.

Comment: If you're still having trouble determining whether the link phase is completing, in spite of correcting your spellings (if you didn't misquote them), you could add -# to echo the construction of the linker script.    ldd is more likely to work if you completed the link but don't have the right LD_LIBRARY_PATH at run time.

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed the compilervars.sh sourcing. Can you remove all other exports and try again? (after a cleaning of all '*.o', '*.so' and '*.mod' files).
Then, make the program and copy-paste here the output of  `ldd abXX` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: So I removed the two `source` commands, but the rest of the export commands in .mybashrc are there either to let this code compile or one of the other codes I run so I didn't remove those. In the end the .mybashrc file looks like it does in the original post. 

The output of `ldd abXX` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` were too long to put in a comment so I have edited the above post to include their output.

Comment: do you have multiple installations of the intel compilers?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm on a university network so I'm not entirely sure. I know I am running different versions of ifort vs icc:

`icc --version: icc (ICC) 16.0.3 20160415`

`ifort --version: ifort (IFORT) 12.1.4 20120410`

Comment: It is not recommended to mix versions. If possible, I suggest to use a single compiler release for ifort and icc and to only load this specific variables file from intel. About anything else is bound to be problematic. As you work in a university, ideally you should ask the IT person in charge of compilers to set this up properly.

Comment: Also, if you need to manage several software stacks you can use Modules http://modules.sourceforge.net/ where you would load a given setup at a time.

Comment: I don't have an /opt/intel directory on my linux box.  What do I need to install?

Comment: @Gdalya `/opt/intel` is one install option, the compilers may be installed somewhere else. If your problem is not exactly the one mentioned here, please open another question.

Comment: Thanks, @PierredeBuyl.  It turns out that I needed to download and install [Intel's Redistributable Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-for-intel-c-and-fortran-2018-compilers-for-windows).