# MATLAB loadlibrary error: Undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove

Tags: matlab, intel, rhel, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a 3rd-party library (`.so` file) into MATLAB under RHEL.

I am getting an error: undefined:symbol: _intel_fast_memmove.

From [Symbol lookup error: _FileName_: undefined symbol: _intel_fast_memmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227312/symbol-lookup-error-filename-undefined-symbol-intel-fast-memmove) it seems like I need to add a sub-directory of /opt/intel to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but I don't have an /opt/intel directory.

UPDATE:

MATLAB said that the problem came when trying to load `libifcoremt.so.5`.  I have since installed [Intel's Redistributable Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-for-intel-c-and-fortran-2019-compilers-for-linux) and all that did was call Intel's version of `libifcoremt.so.5` but still looked for `_intel_fast_memmove` (but still didn't find it).  So now I'm thinking that there must be some other "definitions" file somewhere that I'm missing.

Comment: The 3rd party forgot to provide the run-time library with the .so file. You need to ask them.

Comment: Yeah...unfortunately this is a "legacy" package, so I don't have access to the third party developer.  This hasn't been my first hurdle due to the developer having a different linux configuration than me which produces "hidden" dependencies.

Comment: Try `ldd <libraryname>` from the Linux command line. It should show you what libraries this library needs to link to, and if they're found. Hopefully from there you will be able to determine which version of the Intel runtime libraries you need. You then might be able to download those runtimes from the Intel website. Sorry, this is not something that I can help with remotely... :)

Comment: Thanks, @cris.  If you look at my update, I think that you'll agree that this isn't about missing .so files.  I previously looked at `ldd` and there weren't any missing dependencies.

Comment: The other option is that there is a clash of symbols with other libraries that MATLAB loads. Maybe MATLAB also uses that same Intel library, but a different version. Then when it loads your .so file, it doesn't try to load the Intel library because it already has it, but then there's a symbol missing because it's a different version. I've seen things like this before. I always try to build stuff for MATLAB using static linking to avoid exactly this type of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a few days, but I was able to figure out what was going on.

In the end, there were two problems:

1. I was missing some libraries -- not the ones that I mention in my question, but [Intel's Redistributable Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-for-intel-c-and-fortran-2018-compilers-for-windows).
2. Even with all of the libraries on my computer, MATLAB was still using an older version of the some of the .os files.

   I failed to mention in my question that while the 3rd-party library is fairly recent, I was calling it from MATLAB **2012B** because I needed to integrate it with a software package that doesn't work correctly with later MATLAB versions.  My apologies for that omission -- it turns out to be a critical piece of the puzzle.

   While diagnosing this issue, I learned that MATLAB has it's own copy of the Intel libraries in the `<MATLAB>/sys/os/glnxa64` sub-directory *and* that it creates an internal version of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that points to its internal version before the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that it imports from the Linux OS.  Since the version of MATLAB I'm using is 6 years old, so is it's Intel library, which doesn't contain some symbols defined in the new library, such as `intel_fast_memmove`.

To get the integrated system up and running, I instituted a workaround to rename the `sys/os/glnxa64` before calling the 3rd-party library so that MATLAB found the newer Intel library instead of the MATLAB 2012B version.  And then named it back when done (without that directory, MATLAB won't start).

Note: I first tried editing the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside MATLAB 2012B to prefer the new Intel library, but found that even though the external variable value changed, `loadlibrary` still used the original value that placed MATLAB's library first on the path.